# VPN affect other local PCs or just the one?

Tags: vpn

I think this is obvious but I want to find out anyway.  If you have a PC connecting to work VPN remotely from home over your local high speed connection.  Then you've got a couple other PCs at home, I assume traffic from your other PCs will not even know about or touch that VPN tunnel.

Answer (score 1):

You got it right.  The VPN is created from the client machine, through the internet, to the VPN server.  Only traffic from/to the VPN client is affected.

The only exception I could think of would be if you were using your client computer as a gateway on your home network in some type of connection sharing scheme.

Answer (score 1):

Others PC wont access vpn tunnel in general.

But if you have configure some servises like nat or proxy, or yours vpn is configured like lan-to-lan on your's computer with vpn this will be possible.